# Spring boot doesn't start because of loading url based in application-dev.properties

Tags: spring-boot, rest, uri

I've a problem to load an external endpoint based in application-dev.properties.

To begin, this the part of the service:

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

        URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(externalConfig.getExternalUrlPrefix() + externalConfig.getExternalUrl())
                .path(param)
                .build().toUri();
```

The service use this configuration file:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("external")
@Data
public class ExternalConfig {
    private String externalUrlPrefix;
    private String externalUrl;
}
```

And these url are base in this application-dev.properties:

```
# ===============================
# = EXTERNAL
# ===============================
external.external-url-prefix=https://link/external/rest/
external.external-url=param/
```

First at all, the .properties is detected because I can find database, JPA configuration etc...
second, the uri is good and I can test it in Postman

At the end, the error is in the service, because it doesn't find the value:

```
externalConfig.getExternalUrlPrefix() + externalConfig.getExternalUrl()
```

The error is:

> java: cannot find symbol

I've verified everything and I don't understand the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Cannot find symbol sounds like a compilation problem. I see that you're using Lombok's `@Data`. Is it set up properly in the environment where you're getting the compilation error? I suspect that the getter methods that it should have generated aren't visible to the compiler.

Comment: check your pom.xml; does it have a dependency entry for lombok?

Comment: Ok, so the configuration was good but because I'm behind a proxy, the mvn install doesn't work properly. So I have manually do a mvn clean install and everything is ok. Thanks for your help.